# Are MasterCard and Visa accepted by Amsterdam taxis?

Tags: payment-cards, taxis, amsterdam, payment

Do taxis in Amsterdam accept Visa and MasterCard?

A search reveals that mostly they don't...but the questions and answers I found are 8 or 10 years old.

Is the situation now different?

Comment: I would be surprised if they don't, with everything being paid by card since COVID, but as I do not use taxis and have not been in Amsterdam in almost two years, I am not going to post as an answer.

Comment: @BenWatson: just ask in advance, and the card machine will magically work.

Comment: I was in Amsterdam two weeks ago. The whole payment trouble is the reason why I don't use taxis but only ride share.  Uber worked very well there: they do take card, you know the cost upfront,  and they don't try to take you any detours to run up the meters.

Comment: I suggest you take the ride, and if they can't take a card payment at the destination, then they are a fake taxi. 8 to 10 years ago it was different. Since then London taxis, New York taxis went to card payments kicking and screaming, but now it's done. Pay by card.

Comment: Almost all taxis in the Netherlands have a pin-terminal these days. And those accept Visa and Mastercard too. Taxis that don't are usually illegally operating without permit. But you won't find those at the official Schiphol taxi stand. That is probably the best regulated taxi stand (with very strict permit checks) in the whole of the Netherlands.

Comment: Just be warned the Taxis will probably take Visa/MasterCard but there are a lot of shops in Amsterdam/Netherlands that don't. They want you'd use Maestro card (they'll say no credit card on the machines but they really mean is no Visa/MasterCard even if you have a debit card). You should be okay in the tourist areas but when you leave the center things can get harder, it gets even worse as places are also starting to move away from cash as well.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure about paying the driver directly, but at least TCA and Staxi have an app that supports credit card (and PayPal).

https://www.tcataxi.nl/en/tca-app/
https://www.staxi.nl/en/faq/

This one accepts CC too: https://www.amsterdamtaxi-online.com/

Answer (score 10):

It's a statistical sample of one, but on January 1st 2020, I paid for a taxi from Schiphol to the Amsterdam Marriott with a Visa, and again the next day in the other direction. Apropos of nothing, the first taxi was a Tesla.

Comment: Upvoted for first-hand experience and recognizing that n=1 :)

Comment: @Dave Schiphol taxis are almost all Tesla's. It is a permit thing, Schiphol trying to be "green". You can't get as permit to pick up passengers at the official Schiphol taxi stand unless you car is all electric. Non-electric are still allowed to drop off passengers at Schiphol, but they can't pickup a return at the main taxi stand. They have to return empty or try to find a passenger at one of the hotels or businesses surrounding the airport.